# TranscriptionOptions.__new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'max_new_tokens', 'clip_timestamps', and 'hallucination_silence_threshold'

Tags: docker, openai-whisper

I need some help with this error, I'm using Whisperx to extract text from an audio file, when I run the code via VSCode (on a Mac mini M2) without the transcription options all works as expected, but when I compose up to docker the code fails to run indicating I'm missing 3 argument, I've tried adding those arguments to my code but that's not working either.

```
2024-03-20 22:23:15 test-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-03-20 22:23:15 test-1  |     import speech
2024-03-20 22:23:15 test-1  |   File "/code/speech.py", line 274, in <module>
2024-03-20 22:23:15 test-1  |   File "/code/speech.py", line 69, in get_speeach_to_text
2024-03-20 22:23:15 test-1  |     model = whisperx.load_model("medium", device, compute_type=compute_type)
2024-03-20 22:23:15 test-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/whisperx/asr.py", line 332, in load_model
2024-03-20 22:23:15 test-1  |     default_asr_options = faster_whisper.transcribe.TranscriptionOptions(**default_asr_options)
2024-03-20 22:23:15 test-1  | TypeError: TranscriptionOptions.__new__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'max_new_tokens', 'clip_timestamps', and 'hallucination_silence_threshold'
```

I'm running --platform=linux/arm64 python:3.10

This is my speech.py file code after adding the transcription options, but in reality I prefer not to include them, and I'm running the latest whisperx:

```
import whisperx
import faster_whisper

# Define TranscriptionOptions with example values for the required arguments
transcription_options = faster_whisper.transcribe.TranscriptionOptions(
    beam_size=4,
    best_of=1,
    patience=10,
    length_penalty=0.6,
    repetition_penalty=1.2,
    no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
    log_prob_threshold=-20,
    no_speech_threshold=0.5,
    compression_ratio_threshold=0.5,
    condition_on_previous_text=False,
    prompt_reset_on_temperature=True,
    temperatures=[0.7],
    initial_prompt="",
    prefix="",
    suppress_blank=False,
    suppress_tokens=False,
    without_timestamps=True,
    max_initial_timestamp=60,
    word_timestamps=False,
    prepend_punctuations="",
    append_punctuations="",
    max_new_tokens=50,
    clip_timestamps=60,
    hallucination_silence_threshold=0.5
)

device = "cpu"
batch_size = 16  # reduce if low on GPU mem
compute_type = "int8"

# 1. Transcribe with original whisper (batched)
model = whisperx.load_model("medium", device, compute_type=compute_type)

audio = whisperx.load_audio(source_audio_file)
result = model.transcribe(audio, language='en', task='translate', batch_size=batch_size, transcription_options=transcription_options)
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat emptor: I don't know much about this particular stack, but I took a swing at solving this problem. Happy to iterate towards a working solution.

I think that this is a version compatibility issue. The latest version of `whisperx` on PyPi doesn't appear to include those parameters. You could install the current version of `whisperx` directly from GitHub (this does have those parameters!).

```
whisper==1.1.10
faster-whisper==1.0.0
git+https://github.com/m-bain/whisperX.git
```

This will get you around the `TypeError` but you will likely get a warning about model versions. But that appears to be a separate issue.

```
Model was trained with pyannote.audio 0.0.1, yours is 3.1.1. Bad things might happen unless you revert pyannote.audio to 0.x.
Model was trained with torch 1.10.0+cu102, yours is 2.2.1+cu121. Bad things might happen unless you revert torch to 1.x.
```

Not sure what your `Dockerfile` looks like, but this is what I used for testing:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY speech.py .

CMD python3 speech.py
```

At present it seems that the model is being downloaded at run time and this takes a while. Might make more sense to download the model onto the host and then share with the container via a volume mount? Again, see caveat above. :)